# Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SubCategoryData>'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to assigning the list to list of object, but it is showing the above exception.

```
List<SubCategoryData>categoryNames = new List<SubCategoryData>();
  List<String>categorieslist = [];
  bool isFirst=true;

  Future<SubCategoryModel>fetchCategories(BuildContext context) async {

    String url = "http://106.51.64.251:380/onnet_api/subcatListByCategory.php";

    var body = new Map<String,String>();
    body['publisherid']= 102.toString();
    body['tag'] = "category";
    body['subtag']= "list";
    body['parentId'] = 10.toString();

    http.Response res = await http.post(url,body: body);
    final categoryjsondata = json.decode(res.body);
    var map = Map<String,dynamic>.from(categoryjsondata);
    var categoryResponse = SubCategoryModel.fromJson(map);

    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      print('category Response: $categoryResponse');
      if(categoryResponse.status == 1){
        //final categoryModel = json.decode(res.body);
        categoryNames = categoryjsondata['data']as List;
        print('category data: $categoryNames');

      /*  for(var model in categorieslist){
          categoryNames.add(new SubCategoryData.fromJson(model));
        }*/
    /*    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        print("cat List Size: $categories");
        prefs.setStringList("categorylist", categories);*/
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ChewieDemo(imageData: images[0],
            categoryData:categoryNames.toList())));
      }
    }
  }
```

By seeing my code, for categoryNames I am trying to assigning the data to this then it is showing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to:

```
List<SubCategoryData> categoryNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace the following:

```
categoryNames = categoryjsondata['data']as List;
```

by

```
 for(var model in categoryData){
        categoryNames.add(new SubCategoryData.fromJson(model));
      }
```

because the first returns a List the second returns a List

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resides here:

```dart
categoryNames = categoryjsondata['data']as List;
```

`categoryNames` is already defined and initialized and its type is `List<SubCategoryData>`. In the line above you are trying to assign a `List<dynamic>` to it. That's a different type and that's the cause of the error. If you assign that to some other variable you can use it freely:

```dart
final categoryNamesList = categoryjsondata['data'] as List;
```

BTW then you don't have to call `.toList()` in the next lines, because this variable is already a list.

Answer (score 0):

If explicity not defined the lists are of type `dynamic`, So explicitly state the value of the model. i.e

Convert

```
categoryNames = categoryjsondata['data']as List;
```

to

```
categoryNames = List<SubCategoryData>.from(categoryjsondata['data']);
```